# JSON functions in MBI SQL builder

Tags: database, sql, integration

According to the [docs](https://docs.magento.com/mbi/data-analyst/dev-reports/supp-sql-func.html), all functions that are not mutations should be included in the SQL syntax.  I have a MySQL integration in MBI, but when I try to test some basic SQL functions such as `JSON_EXTRACT()` in the SQL terminal, the query errors out.

For example:

```
SELECT '{"a":1, "b":"stringdata"}'::json AS json
```

will work both in a regular MySQL terminal and MBI SQL builder

However,

```
SELECT JSON_EXTRACT('{"a":1, "b":"stringdata"}', "$.b")
```

Will work in a regular MySQL terminal but **not** in MBI SQL builder.

How does one get around these discrepancies and is there a definitive list of functions supported by MBI?

Answer (score 0):

This works!

```
SELECT '{"a":1, "b":"stringdata"}'::json->'b'
```